# How to install Samba on Redhat 6, getting error

Tags: files, rhel, yum, samba

I'm having trouble installing Samba (and really any other programs and services) on my Redhat 6 server. I keep getting this error:
[image: error message]

I've been having this trouble when using the yum command. So I've been doing work around, downloading rpms and install by unpacking that. But the rpm I found for samba isn't working. Any other sources I can download the RPM from?!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange.  Suggest you :  (1) place the command+error into the question as text, not image.  (2) update question to include the contents of that offending .repo file.

Answer (score 3):

You have a configuration file that doesn't belong to the distribution and doesn't contain the right content. You should fix this or remove that file, and install RPMs from your distribution, not some random RPMs you find on the internet.

Comment: Is the file the file://etc.yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo?

Comment: Yes, the error message is about /etc.yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo. Try moving the file to a different directory, or if you don't know why it is there, remove it, and see whether yum is able to install samba after that.

Comment: `/etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo`